# knockout js change the bindings with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have problem with `knockout` binding, i'm trying to change the value of the viewmodel by jquery but i can't do that!

i'm learning knockout,

```
mi.data = {
    title: ko.observable("Page Title")
};

mi.data.title = "Some New Value"
```

html >

```
<h1 data-bind="text: title"></h1>
```

and here is a link on jsFiddle from what i have tried. what i'm missing?

[what i have tried](http://jsfiddle.net/TRHFb/1/)

Comment: Why do you want to change the value with jquery?

Comment: this is sample of my code, in my real project changing values happens some other ways, i just want to see what i can do about it

Answer (score 3):

Each observable is a function so to assign value to it you should pass value as a parameter:

```
mi.data.title("Some New Value");
```

To get value from observable you should call it:

```
var value = mi.data.title();
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TRHFb/2/

Answer (score 1):

Observable is a function not variable. 
So you have to pass in value like:
`i.data.title(Math.random().toString());`
in your case.